# Excel 2013: Hiding "0 hours 00 minutes" elapsed time

Tags: excel, numbers, format, excel-2013, elapsedtime

I am customizing Excel's built-in Time Card template to calculate overtime hours per day. I customized the time format as [h] "hours" mm "minutes". But the problem comes for a day which doesn't have overtime hours, so I get "0 hours 00 minutes" in the cell. I want to show '--' in those cells. How do I do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter this custom number format:

```
[h] "hours" mm "minutes";;--
```

**UPDATE**

The problem you were experiencing is that Excel is not good with decimal ([floating point](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/78113)) arithmetic. It can be off by very tiny amounts. Your calculations that looked like they resulted in zero were instead something like: 0.0000000033.

To get around this problem I used the MROUND() function to round the calculations to the nearest minute. This resulted in real zeroes and allowed the number format to do its thing.

Like so:

```
=MROUND(E15-G15,60/86400)
```

The number format given at the top of this answer works perfectly after that.

Comment: I'm here to help if you can tell me how it did not work.

Comment: I'm still seeing "0 hours 00 minutes", only empty fields have '--'

Comment: So the text you are seeing is being produced by formula instead of number formatting. What is the exact title of the template? I've looked and there are a number of time card templates.

Comment: I'm happy to take a look at it if I can find it.

Comment: When you Click on "New" in Excel, aka the Start Screen, there is a Time Card template there, at least on my side. Hope you can find it. However, I don't think the template has anything to do with it, because I formatted the cells myself.

Comment: Yeah, the templates that any give user sees on the "New" screen are variable. No timecard template showing up here. At any rate, if you can email me your file I can get it sorted quickly. My email address is:  daniel.ferry@gmail.com